# Spring dependency injection with static constructors

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have been using Guice for a few years now and just switched to a company that uses Spring.  I am a fan of Dependency Injection but having a few issues figuring out how to get Spring to do what I want.

Here is what I have in the code right now (its not scala code, just shorter so using that syntax):

```
class A(b: B)
class B(exe: ExecutorService)
...
@Value("${search.threads}") var searchThreads: int
exe = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(searchThreads)
```

In guava I could use Named annotations to have different executors, or just use one executor for anyone that needed it and just define

```
final int searchThreads = readSearchThreadsFromConfigs()
bind(Executor.class).toInstance(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(searchThreads));
```

I am not sure how to set this up within Spring.  It seems every example I see doesn't really cover generics, nor does it really go over static constructors or being able to "provide" the value.

What is the best way to get similar results to what I had above from Guice?  Is there a notion of a "module" like guice and dagger use (other than the xml file, something statically checked)?

EDIT:
Here is a bit of the code currently used.  It creates the executor within the constructor:

```
@Autowired
public LogsModule(@Value("${search.threads}") final int searchThreads) {
  searchPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(searchThreads);
}
```

Comment: Its a java project, but I didn't feel like copy/paste/cutting all over, so tried to give a jist above.

Comment: Updated to show the current constructor that I would like to change.

Comment: You aren't actually autowiring anything into the `LogsModule` constructor. Are you trying to declare beans for injection?

Comment: in the constructor i am passed an int that is used to create the executor.  I would like to replace that with the executor itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Spring it's basically the same.

Your example can be rewritten as follows using [`@Configuration`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java):

```
@Bean(value = "searchExecutor", destroyMethod = "shutdownNow")
public ExecutorService executorService(Environment env) {
    final int searchThreads = env.getProperty("searchThreads", Integer.class, 3);
    return Executors.newFixedThreadPool(searchThreads));
}
```

This example uses `Environment` - you can either add properties from your config to it, or use your config directly instead.

With XML configuration it would be more complex, but you can mix `@Configuration` with XML.

If you need multiple executors, you can use `@Qualifier` (or perhaps `@Named`) to distinguish between candidates by their bean names:

```
@Autowired
public LogsModule(@Qualifier("searchExecutor") ExecutorService e) { ... }
```

Comment: Could you not use `@Named` directly and remove the `@Autowired` and `@Qualifier`?

Comment: Where do you put the "public ExecutorService executorService(Environment env) {" ?  Is it in the class that is getting the value?  Is it a stand alone class?

Comment: @ekaqu You can set up your container programatically. See [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java)

Comment: Reading the javadocs for Configuration, it seems more clear how to add the bean.  will go try that

Comment: Adding a LogConfiguration class with Configuration did the trick.  I can now put my logic here when autowire doesn't pick it up!  Also Named isn't in the classpath, so I ended up using Qualifier